# Formatting of double-sided document

Tags: double-sided

I have a small issue with the final formatting of my thesis. I would like to print double-sided. However, my document is defined as one-sided and I individually defined the margins using the geometry package (see below):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=32mm, left=28mm, right=28mm, bottom=32mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
```

When I change the settings to two-sided it does not work, because I pre-defined the margins etc. However, if I remove my pre-defined margins and use the "**twoside**" command, the line spacing etc. becomes very small and I have around 20 pages less.

Is there any feasible way to get around this problem?

Many thanks for your help, highly appreciated.

Comment: Change `left`/`right` to `inner`/`outer` and add the twoside option.

Comment: The isue is not printing double sided but rather leaving extra space for the binding.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. It works, however, it does not give me empty pages after acknoloedgement, toc, etc. and also prints the toc etc. with inner and outer margins. How can I change that it only does that from chapter 1?

Comment: Easy solution, just add \cleardoublepage where needed, or use book instead of article.